# Ubuntu MySQL installation problems

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, terminal

I have used 'sudo apt-get install mysql-server', and it asks me if I want to install 2 files.

```
mysql-server is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 7 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]?
```

I enter Y (for yes)

The configure window pops up asking to set the root password.
I enter it, and it continues the install.

All goes well...Until;

```
120420 14:47:45  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
120420 14:47:46  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1595685
start: Job failed to start
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: So what do the logs say about why MySQL failed to start?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at mysql logs, I'm sure you'll find some pretty easy-to-fix reason why it won't start.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't generate any log. A lot of people have reported this as a bug but I can't find a solution in any website.